# ASP.NET: Creating and using a subfolder of bin

Tags: asp.net, plugins, web-config

I am creating some plugin dlls that validate my website's configuation at startup.  I want to place these dlls in a subdirectory of the /bin folder.  So I added this to my web.config file:

```
<runtime>
   <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin;bin/plugins" />
      ...
</runtime>
```

And then I have a project that builds and deploys some dlls into the /bin/plugins directory.

I have verified that the build step is correct and creates the subfolder and puts the dlls in there.

Then on application_start, I try to load the assemblies.  I get the currently executing assemblies path like so:

```
    Dim assembly As Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim asmDirectory As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location)
    Dim pluginDirectory As String = Path.Combine(asmDirectory, "plugins")
```

pluginDirectory usually is set to something like this:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\91be3168\7a998462\assembly\dl3\33ada1a0\6561a9fc_a4dacd01"
```

But in that directory, there is no plugins directory.

How do I get IIS (IIS 6.0 in my case) to copy the subfolder and contents from my code directory to the execution location?

If the VB.NET is too difficult to read, I am happy to translate to C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior that copies assemblies there is called [Shadow Copying](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/02/09/69919.aspx). In order to enable it, ASP.NET calls [AppDomain.SetShadowCopyPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setshadowcopypath.aspx) (it's an obsolete API, but that's still what it calls), passing the path to the bin folder only.

That is why you don't see your assemblies in the sub-folder getting shadow copied. That behavior is not configurable. Besides, even if it were, it wouldn't work the way you want because it would not recreate the same structure as you have in bin.

Instead of relying on the executing assembly path, you could just call [HttpRuntime.BinDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.bindirectory.aspx), which will give you the path to bin, to which you can append your plugins folder.